# PHP preg_replace url string

Tags: php, preg-replace

Ok, so I have a preg_replace statement to replace a url string.
First and second variable working but I need help for second string sub ....

```
$html = str_replace('index.php','index',$html);
$html = preg_replace('/index\?cat=([a-z0-9]+)/i','index/$1',$html);
$html = preg_replace('/index\?cat=([a-z0-9]+)/&sub=([a-z0-9]+)/i','index/$1/$2',$html);
```

Comment: you mean you need help with third? try escaping ampersand at &sub with \&sub

Comment: Remove the `/` right before `&sub` probably. Also, do the more specific replace _first_, the less specific one _later_. If that does not help, please specify input & desired output. Also note, that with proper error reporting, PHP would already have told you what was wrong with it.

Comment: Escape / as \/ like Wrikken mentioned

Comment: I get this index/test&sub=text

Comment: Can you give us the $html?

Comment: function self_urls_convert($html) {
$html = str_replace('index.php','index',$html);
$html = preg_replace('/index\?cat=([a-z0-9]+)/i','index/$1',$html);
$html = preg_replace('/index\?cat=([a-z0-9]+)/&sub=([a-z0-9]+)/i','index/$1/$2',$html);
return $html;
}

$output = ob_get_contents();
$output = self_urls_convert($output);

Answer (score 2):

Assuming `$html` contains:

```
index.php?cat=123&sub=456
```

after the `str_replace` $html becomes:

```
index?cat=123&sub=456
```

after the first preg_replace:

```
index/123&sub=456
```

Then the second preg_replace doesn't match.

You'd better to modify the order of the preg_replace:

```
//$html  ->  index.php?cat=123&sub=456
$html = str_replace('index.php','index',$html);
//$html  ->  index?cat=123&sub=456
$html = preg_replace('/index\?cat=([a-z0-9]+)&sub=([a-z0-9]+)/i','index/$1/$2',$html);
//$html  ->  index/123/456
$html = preg_replace('/index\?cat=([a-z0-9]+)/i','index/$1',$html);
//$html  ->  index/123/456
```